# Creating a "Global" AlertDialog

Tags: android

hey guys im trying to create a AlertDialog with user text input inside of it
since in my app I need atleast like 3 of those I thought it will be a great idea to create one AlertDialog method that will return the value user has typed in it
into a specific method and by this save on writing alot of code

heres a sample of my code

```
public void alrtDialog(String setTitle, String setPositiveBtn)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);//<--create alert dialog builder
    myDialog.setTitle(setTitle);
    final EditText myText = new EditText(context);
    myText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    myDialog.setView(myText);
    Log.e("blalba", "texoutt:" + myText.getText().toString());
    myDialog.setPositiveButton(setPositiveBtn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            setMsg(myText.getText().toString());//<--set
            Log.e("blalba", "teinxt:" + myText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    myDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
    return getMsg();
}
```

Comment: create a DialogFragemnt then just use that everywhere

Comment: Note answer, if it suite you. To note just check mark...

Answer (score 2):

**Create DialogFragment**

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("Simple Dialog");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Show in any context**

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment ();
dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");
```